# Is there a word for the feeling of wanting something material?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you see an attractive pizza and feel desire, you can say, "I feel hungry". If you see an attractive person and feel desire, you can say, "I feel lust". If you see an attractive car and feel desire, you can say, "I feel _____ ?"

Is there a single word that describes the desire for something material?

I'm thinking "greedy", but that implies a desire for more material possessions generally, it's not specific to seeing a single item and wanting it. "Desire", of course, is accurate, but again that is too general - it's not specific to material goods. Is there a word (or maybe short phrase) specifically describing the desire to acquire a particular item?

Comment: @Josh61 no, that's an obsession with shopping generally - I'm looking for a word that means a desire for a single specific object. i.e. bob says: "every time I see a jaquar drive by, I think to myself I must have one of those" - he is feeling, what?

Comment: "Oniomania" sounds like an uncontrollable urge to buy onions. ;)

Comment: (And note that an uncontrollable urge to buy what you see may make you a "shopaholic".)

Comment: @HotLicks "Shallotholic"

Comment: @CalebBernard - That's an uncontrollable urge to buy hoity-toity onions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes: **[covetous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/covetous):**

> feeling or showing a very strong desire for something that you do not have and especially for something that belongs to someone else [M-W]

If you want a noun, *covetousness.* But here is one case where the verb does most nicely: “I covet that.”

If you can denominate sexual desire with the term *lust,* I anticipate no insuperable problem with the [scriptural baggage](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020%3A17&version=KJV) of *covet.*

Comment: This is not a word I would have thought of, as I don't think I've ever heard it used, but I think the definition is the best match. Future readers might also consider *crave*, which is similar, but implies more of a physical or emotional need.

Answer (score 7):

Somewhat obvious suggestion, but how about ***[materialistic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/materialistic)***?

> **1)** The theory or attitude that physical well-being and worldly possessions constitute the greatest good and highest value in life.
>
> **2)** Concern for possessions or material wealth and physical comfort, especially to the exclusion of spiritual or intellectual pursuits.

thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 5):

Being *covetous* often implies what you want belongs to *someone else* (which could even include [your neighbour's *wife*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22covet%20your%20neighbour%27s%20wife%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) as well as his *ass*).

To my ear, *acquisitiveness* might simply imply a tendency to accumulate possessions (by not discarding things you no longer need, as well as being keen to acquire them in the first place).

So I suggest:

> [**avarice**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/avarice) *- extreme greed for **wealth or material gain***

Comment: Would you strongly desire to by a new car out of *avarice*? To me avarice is just the opposite of spending money for pleasure ( cars etc.)

Comment: @Josh61: I'm not sure a strong desire to ***buy*** things is necessarily an expression of avarice. You might just be a feckless spendthrift, for example, or someone who likes to *show off, impress* others with your flashy expensive possessions. To me, *avarice* is more about greedily seeking to own things, well reflected in my cited definition.

Comment: +1 FF for avarice and the distinction you draw with covetous

Answer (score 4):

*Caveat emptor*: this answer, offered with levity, is directed specifically toward the example of the desire felt toward an automobile, rather than toward material objects in general, which I believe is a manifestation of [*MATERIALISM*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/materialism).

Well, if this was a simple one to one proposition, like hunger is [***want***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/want) of food, and lust *want* of sex, then perhaps you could say that the desire for a car was *want* of mobility, i.e., [**immobility**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immobile), or the feeling of being ... [stuck](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick) i.e., *blocked*, *wedged*, or *jammed*. (links are to Merriam-Webster *online*)

Unfortunately, I think that this *want* is less directly tied to the issue of mobility in general, and is instead, highly specific, often directed toward a *certain* car, one *particular* car out of many cars (I know. I've seen the *look*.).  So, perhaps the best way to describe this ... *desire*, is just to call it what it obviously is: *lust*. In this case, **Car Lust**.  ;-)

> [**Car Lust**](http://definithing.com/car-lust/): extreme desire of an automobile. Usually happens after driving an awesome car, usually a friend’s or a rental. “Dudes, I have serious *car lust* after driving that 1969 corvette!”

(For definitions of "Car Lust," *see* definithing.com & the Urban Dictionary)

[image]

**Exhibit A**

Comment: +1 for *car lust* or *boat envy*

Comment: To be confused with neither objectum sexuality nor autosexuality!

Comment: Yes @Caleb, we can definitely exclude '*autosexuality*' (that's very good!), but I think you should post '*objectum sexuality*' as an answer. Seriously.

Answer (score 3):

I think  ***[acquisitive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquisitive)***  comes close to what you are looking for:

> - inclined or eager to acquire things, esp material.

(Collins Dict.)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible word could be **longing**
"He had a longing for the beautiful painting."

Defined as: a strong desire for something, particularly something unattainable.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not commonly used (in my experience) in the first person, **to hunger for** something seems very close to what you want. It evokes the intense, immediate desire for something tangible, such as food, but can be used to speak about desire for almost any material object.

It can also be used for less material concepts, such as hungering for love or fame.

From "Country Joe and the Fish"'s song, "Porpoise Mouth":

> I hunger for your porpoise mouth, and stand erect for love.

Answer (score 0):

Covet is also the word that first came to mind for me.  You covet the car.  However, can covet anything - a person, money, items, activities.  It is not necessarily "material"

Maybe materialistic?  Materialism is the state of desiring material things, to to "feel materialistic" would be wanting material things.