# What is the word for being too greedy for money?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

I need a word that implies

a person's insatiable hunger for more than required wealth

Something like "hoard" or "more than required" but not quite

Comment: Please ....[we just did this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515897/the-feeling-of-always-wanting-newer-possessions) , it was closed twice, but is now active.

Comment: @Cascabel  the "New contributor" badge  means that I am not an expert on this site

Comment: I understand that. Sorry if I came off surly.

Comment: np, just learned a new word surly

Comment: I learn something new everyday participating on this site. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think  it  is **avarice**. Excessive  greed  for  wealth

Here is a link.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/avarice